# Oracle SQL: ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.AGEDETAILS' is invalid and failed re-validation

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

This is the code for my trigger in Oracle PL/SQL:

```
   create or replace trigger checkemp
   before insert or update 
   on employee
   for each row
   declare
   age number;
   begin
   if(:new.age>50)
   then
   insert into nonemp values(:new.emp,:new.empname);
   end if;
   end;
   /
```

When I type in the following statement:

```
     insert into employee values(3434,'dfjkhsfk','dkjfhdfd','12-AUG-94',60);
```

Oracle gives me the error

```
     ERROR at line 1:

     ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.AGEDETAILS' is invalid and failed re-validation
```

The code is supposed to store emp(employee number) and empname(employee name) into the table nonemp.

Please help.

Comment: What are the errors? If you're using SQL*Plus type `show error` after compiling the trigger and you'll see...

Comment: Do ***NOT*** create objects in the `SYSTEM` tablespace. Just don't! Stop right now and create a regular user to do your development work.

Comment: Also age varies with time, and you can't put a trigger on that so store date of birth instead

Answer (score 0):

you look like you have another trigger "agedetails", please disable it, and try again.

Comment: the created trigger is checkemp, and the error is regarding AGEDETAILS

Answer (score 0):

Run the below statement:

```
SELECT
      UPPER ( OBJECT_NAME ),
      COUNT ( * )
FROM
      DBA_OBJECTS
WHERE
         OBJECT_TYPE = 'TRIGGER'
      AND STATUS = 'INVALID'
      AND OBJECT_NAME = 'AGEDETAILS'
GROUP BY
      UPPER ( OBJECT_NAME )
HAVING
      COUNT ( * ) > 1;
```

If returns any row then, you should be having two triggers in the same name with different cases. In that case, please drop one trigger, Possibly the old one (Verify before dropping)

Comment: sorry for this question but why do we write 'create or REPLACE' and there is still possibility of an existence of on old triger. It shouldnt be replaced ? realspirituals

Comment: No. it replaces only when you have the same object (CASE SENSITIVE). @Moudiz

Comment: What makes you think there was an existing trigger with the same name? The OP's trigger is being created with errors, and would replace one that already exists.

Comment: I faced this issue once, where accidentally the developer formatted the code in TOAD which converted the TRIGGER name into ALL CAPS. Also I suspect the OP has cooked his error message. @AlexPoole

Comment: @realspirituals - if you had another trigger with a case-sensitive name that is different (e.g. `"AgeDetails"`) then it would have no impact on the one the OP is trying to create - they are different objects...

Comment: @realspirituals If I write 'create or replace triger moudiz' then I write 'create or repalce triger Moudiz'. In this case I will have 2 trigers but with different case and then I will got an error as you explained ?

Comment: @Moudiz - Oracle is case-insensitive (in this context) by default. You would have to do `create or replace trigger "moudiz"` then `create or replace trigger "Moudiz"`, with quoted identifiers, to get two objects, which would be independent; but then you would get an error if they were trying to trigger on the same event. With your version the second trigger would replace the first - no error is implied that way.

Comment: Ideally you should receive compilation error on the second trigger if the names are enclosed by ""

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SCOTT"."TEST"
 AFTER UPDATE OF "ENAME"
 ON EMP
BEGIN
 UPDATE
    EMP
 SET
    JOB = 'job2';
END;
/

-- TRIGGER CREATED.

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "SCOTT"."test"
 AFTER UPDATE OF "ENAME"
 ON EMP
BEGIN
 UPDATE
    EMP
 SET
    JOB  = 'job2';
END;
/
--Warning: Trigger created with compilation errors.

UPDATE
   EMP
SET
   ENAME = 'miller1'
WHERE
   EMPNO = 7934;
      
--ERROR at line 1:
--ORA-04098: trigger 'test' is invalid and failed re-validation

DROP TRIGGER "test";
--Trigger dropped.

UPDATE
   EMP
SET
   ENAME = 'miller1'
WHERE
   EMPNO = 7934;
--1 row updated.

Comment: @realspirituals - that's because they're on the same event, it's nothing to do with the names; you could call the second one anything and see the same thing. You cannot infer anything about the actual problem from the ORA-04098. There's nothing in the question to suggest it's an event clash (or a name problem). The OP hasn't shown the actual compilation error - see Ben's first comment.

Comment: Thats why I suspect whether OP has cooked his error message or it is actually another trigger blocking the same